# How to store logs in a custom object based on response from a system

Tags: apex, rest-api

I am calling a rest API and I want to store logs in a custom object logInfo__c if I get a success response then loglevel should set to info. If I get a error or exception then log level should be set to error. If I get a warning in a response then log level should be set to warn. How to achieve this please tell the logic

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. We cannot provide step-by-step or hands-on implementation guidance, but we're happy to help you with issues you encounter in your own implementation process. For more about our format, please take the [Tour] and read [ask] and [On Topic](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please [edit] your question to show us *what you've tried* and *where you are stuck*.

Answer (score 1):

Vijay, there are a couple of things to consider:

1. Separation of concerns - the caller class/method should not be responsible for logging. We consider logging as a cross-cutting concern therefore I recommend having a separate logger class that will encapsulate logger functionality.
2. Need for nullification because logging is a DML, therefore you must consider that.
3. Additional DML is a cost, I think it's not a case to worry about, but keep in mind that for the expensive transaction it must be performed asynchronously (there are many ideas on how to handle that i.e. via platform events and async triggers)
4. Create record types for logInfo__c to distinguish between info, error, exception
5. Logging logic should consider info, errors (from rest), exceptions (i.e. when remote service is unreachable)
6. Use expressive patterns/idioms to instantiate logger i.e. singleton

But as of now let's keep this simple. In general, I assume it will work this way:

```
public class LoggerImpl { 

  private static LoggerImpl loggerInstance = null;
  
  public static LoggerImpl getInstance() {
    if (LoggerImpl.loggerInstance == null) { LoggerImpl.loggerInstance = new LoggerImpl(); } 
    return loggerInstance;
  }


  public void logInfo(string message); { // insert RT=info record} }
  public void logError(string errorMessage); { // insert RT=error record }
  public void logException(string errorMessage, Exception ex); { // insert RT=exception record }
}
```

Note that if you "just insert" you're working on ONE record so it's not bulkified. But I think it's ok if you never put the logger calls within the loop :)

Example usage:

```
public class RestCaller {
  public void doTheCallout() {
    try {
      // do the REST callout
      if (restResponseOK) {
         LoggerImpl.getInstance().logInfo('REST callout OK');
      } else {
         LoggerImpl.getInstance().logError('REST callout ERROR');
      }
      
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       LoggerImpl.getInstance().logException('REST callout EXCEPTION', ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one logic

```
String responseCode = String.valueOf(RestApIResponseStatusCode);

If(responseCode.charAt(0) == 4 || response code.charAt(0) ==5)
{
Debug level is error
}
else
{
Debug level is info
}
```

Correct me if I am wrong
Here error status code start from 400 to 599 so I used to compare the first number 4 and 5